# $.getJSON not returning results

Tags: javascript, html, json

I need to make a page that allows users to search to get a wikipedia page with their results.

The relevant HTML is:

```
<form class='search-form' onsubmit='return false'>
  <input class='search-input' id="search-input" type="text" />
  <button class='btn search-btn'><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</form>
```

And the JS is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".search-btn").on("click", function() {
    $.getJSON(
      "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=te&format=json",
      function(data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      }
    );
  });
});
```

Once I get this alert to run, I need to change the alert to open a window with a URL contained in the JSON data, but I'll cross that bridge when I get to it. For now, the JSON is doing nothing at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll never get there, as the URL doesn't have CORS headers, and can't be accessed from clientside code

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: That basically means you're not doing it correctly, as the URL can't be reached from a browser using ajax. Wikipedia does however support JSONP instead, if you use the correct parameters.

Comment: *"What does that mean? "* You can only make *Ajax* requests to the same server or to external servers *if* they have CORS enabled. This server does not enable CORS, hence you cannot make an Ajax request to it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy for more information.

Comment: @adeneo: Interestingly, in the example in the docs does not use JSONP: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page .

Comment: @FelixKling - that is interesting, and even that example seems to fail due to the same-origin policy when testing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to make a request to Wikipedia that returns JSONP, which makes it possible to do cross-origin requests without CORS headers

```js
function getWiki(query) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
    data: {
      format: 'json',
      action: 'opensearch',
      search: query
    },
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: 'jsonp'
  });
}

$('.search-form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var q = $('#search-input').val();
  
  getWiki(q).done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
  }).fail(function(err) {  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class='search-form'>
  <input class='search-input' id="search-input" type="text" />
  <button class='btn search-btn'>Search</button>
</form>
```